# Singular/plural forms of objects with “respectively”

Tags: ellipses

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

1. A and B are the minimum and maximum **value**, respectively.
2. A and B are the minimum and maximum **values**, respectively.

I tend to think that the first one is correct as it is a reduced version of the following sentence:

3. A and B are the minimum **value** and **the** maximum value, respectively.

In other words, sentence 1 is sentence 3 with two ellipses.

This question was originally a part of [that one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335169/singular-and-plural-forms-and-ellipses). However, it had been left unaddressed there.

Comment: Ivan, have you done any research? Questions should show what research was done, and why you question the results.

Comment: @Davo, I haven’t found any similar questions. If you know any, please feel free to refer to them and mark this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Ivan, as Davo asked, have you done any research?*Research* might include, but is by no means limited to, finding similar questions.

//eithe way, why d'you think a Question like this would not be more suitably answered at English Language Learners, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I’m not sure how much prior research is required to be done in order to become eligible to ask a question here, but I did try to find an answer by googling and then searching here before posting. Also, you seem to imply that there are some restrictions on what can be asked about English here. I’d be grateful if you could refer me to the page where all these rules are formulated and explained so that I do it the right way next time.

Comment: Would you say 'She bought the red and blue dress' was a viable deleted form of 'She bought the red dress and the blue dress' (I won't bother repeating the 'she bought' of the prototypical sentence)? Your (2) is certainly correct. (1) is contestable, what with the existence of distributive singulars and what have you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I guess I misinterpret the whole concept of ellipsis. Those two I mentioned do not qualify, and that’s where my reasoning breaks.

Comment: Deletions are very common in English, especially in conversation. Even ones that lead to ambiguities are sometimes used idiomatically, but one has to be careful. To get a feel for them, look up 'conversational deletion' and just 'deletion' here.

Comment: Ivan, scroll to the bottom of the page and check out Tour and Help, among other handy links.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, thank you! It was very helpful. Now I see EL&U in a totally new light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is correct.

The descriptor of *value* in this context is  **the minimum and maximum**. If you were saying this alone, would you say

- **minimum and maximum value**
- **minimum and maximum values**

Since there are two parts to the descriptor, *minimum* and *maximum*, **value** must get pluralized to **values**.

Another way you can look at this is by taking out the middle part of the sentence. In this case, which of the following is correct?

- **A and B are the value**
- **A and B are the values**

Again, the second one is clearly correct, because A and B are both being modified by **values**.

From a grammatical perspective, **respectively** is irrelevant here. While it may change the feel/mood of the sentence, it does not change its core meaning. By that, I mean you can get rid of it and the sentence will still mean roughly the same thing. Thus, the first part of the sentence must be treated independently.

Comment: Then my reasoning should be incorrect. Where does it fail?

Comment: If _respectively_ indeed makes no difference, it should be plural, I agree.

Comment: Okay. If you think that this response answered your question, please mark it as such. Or if you have further questions/want to wait for additional responses, that's okay too.

Comment: You really need to provide some authoritative support for this answer. I tend to agree with the plural *values* in this exact sentence, but would ordinarily default to 'minimum and maximum value' when they are less explicitly individuated. Here, I think 'A and B are' serves to create entities out of what is normally a concept. But it could still go either way - how real or conceptual are A and B? Are they written down? That is pretty real. Or are they just minima and maxima on a curve drawn on a chalkboard? Are we going to do anything with them? Google Scholar yields 25k hits for the singular.

Comment: @PhilSweet, could you please give an example of when you “would ordinarily default to ‘minimum and maximum value’”?

Comment: @Ivan In nearly all of the 25000 instances in google scholar, and a fair percentage of the cases where the authors chose to use *values*, as well. * Creep mutation is applied to each attribute's minimum and maximum value with a probability denoted as the creep rate.* This one is quite interesting because the values are nominalized to a fairly high degree. *Each* seems to be bleeding over to things it oughtn't really govern. Lifted from [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/350030/?reload=true) using a google scholar search for 'minimum and maximum value'

Comment: @nmg49, regarding the second part of your answer, why do you say that “A and B are the value” in isolation is incorrect? The cardinality before verbs and the one after don’t have to match, do they? And verbs inflect for subjects, not objects, don’t they? You can say, for instance, that “Alice and Bob are a good team,” can’t you?