# Is the object singular or plural in the presence of "respectively"?

Tags: grammar

Is the object singular or plural in the presence of "respectively"? 
Let's see two different examples:
(1) A and B represent the conductivity of the material and the solution, respectively? 
(2) A and B represent the conductivity at saturated state for the material and the solution, respectively?
In both cases, should the "conductivity" be singular or plural?

Comment: The singular works, absolutely without problems.

Comment: Singular. I read an implied (or elided) *each* with respectively: A and B *(each)* represent (something), respectively.

Comment: Then how about this case: (1) A and B are the value for C and D, respectively. (2) A and B are the values for C and D, respectively.

Comment: I found a case here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/415098/singular-plural-forms-of-objects-with-respectively