# Using respectively to define parameters in a math equation: Singluar or plural verb?

Tags: verbs, adverbs, verb-agreement

There are a lot of questions/discussions about using **singular** or **plural** verbs with **respectively**, and the answer is always a **singular** verb. Does using a **singular** verb also apply while defining the terms of a math equation. For example, let's say we have the math equation:

> x =b+c

Then, the norm is to define the parameters x, b, and c immediately after the math equation as

> x=b+c,

1. where x, b, and c **are** the velocity, absolute velocity, and relative velocity, respectively.
2. where x, b, and c **is** the velocity, absolute velocity, and relative velocity, respectively.

Which one is correct: 1 or 2? I have come across a lot of academic articles that uses 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular/plural forms of subjects with “respectively”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335169/singular-plural-forms-of-subjects-with-respectively) 'The schemas of the A and B buffers are called C and D, respectively.': plural verb form.

Comment: In general a subject with the form of a coordination of NPs linked by _and_ take a plural verb, and hence plural "are" is correct here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The fact that this clause is about a mathematical topic has no bearing on this question. Questions about specialized math syntaxes are off-topic here, but this is no different than "snakes, groundhogs, and eagles are reptiles, mammals, and birds, respectively."
2. The use of "respectively" does nothing odd to the grammar of the clause. It's simply a clarifying word.
3. That means you have a simple syntax of "a, b, and c **are** x, y, and z." Plural subject demands plural verb. "Respectively" is simply there to clarify that the order of the second series corresponds to the order of the first series. BUT...
4. This is one of so many times when it's simply not needed. Even without it, no reasonable reader could suppose that the first item in the first series is equivalent to the second or third item in the second series. "Respectively" is needed in sentences like this: "Billy, Jane, and Bob ate hamburger, fries, and soda." With no clarification, this might mean that they each ate all three things, or that "collectively" their eating added up to all three things, but if I add "respectively," we know that Billy had the hamburger, Jane had the fries, and Bob had the soda. In the mathematical clause under consideration here, though, there is no opportunity for confusion and no need for "respectively."